# Handlebars.net with Xamarin not working in Release

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, handlebars.net

With current Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.107, I am trying to process xml and json files with Handlebars.net (1.7.1) and Newtonsoft.json(9.0.1), while in Debug all works fine in Relase is json data not injected. In plani C# console project everything works too.

Any thoughts?

```
string xmlSource = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                        <content>
                          <location longitude=""{{longitude}}"" latitude=""{{latitude}}"" precision=""{{precision}}"" />
                        </content>";

string jsonData = @"{
    ""longitude"" : 16.605371,
    ""latitude"" : 49.180376,
    ""precision"" : 10,
}";

var jsonDataEx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonData);
var template = Handlebars.Compile(xmlSource);
var result = template(jsonDataEx);
```

Comment: You log cat and see details of the application in release.

Comment: It turned out it was a bug in Xamarin, after update to latest Alpha all work again. Ty for help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Xamarin bug. After updating of Xamarin to the latest alpha all is working.

I can only quess that problem was related to linker: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/